# Data Mining and patterns recognition in CSV file (Python ML)

Tags: java, python, mining, anomaly-detection

I am new to the world of ML and data mining and looking for the help and guidance to find unusual behavior on my log file.

Assuming I have a cvs file which logs users sessions start time and end time and the policy numbers that they have worked on similar to below.

Start_date, username, end_date, Policy_numbers 
2018-01-02 10:01, user1, 2018-01-02 10:10, PO-123 
2018-01-02 10:05, user2, 2018-01-02 10:20, PO-456 
2018-01-02 10:11, user1, 2018-01-02 10:45, PO-789 | PO-999  (| is delimiter here)

Is there any Python or java library/module/code or open-source application to identify patterns such as : Most users logged in during 10 AM to 5 PM , Average number of sessions per days in a month, Average length of session and … , 
**I expect application recognize various of patterns and suggest it to me in a list or way that I can pick those one which matters to business.**

*(If I recognize the pattern then I can find the answers by some queries and no need for pattern recognition- that would be an easy job to do)*

Then is there a way to train the system by these recognized patterns to find unusual behaviors such as : find users who logged in after 5:00 PM , find sessions took way longer than average and ...

Thanks for any thought.